# HTML round corners Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, rounded-corners

How can i do round corners like this website has in some places..
I searched everywhere and found lots of code that i got confused which one to use

```
-moz-border-radius:10px;

-webkit-border-radius:10px;

behavior:url(border-radius.htc);
```

Which one should i use ? and why isn't it working with Internet Explorer ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

wow lots of duplicates but alright
Here is the code taken from jQuery UI 
These are CSS statements, you need to add them between `<style></style>` or inside a CSS stylesheet and link them to your HTML file
What each does is add corners to a specific region (Top, Bottom, Top Left, Top Right, All ...)

You can modify the radius everywhere to make them bend more..

```
.ui-corner-tl { -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px; border-top-left-radius: 8px; -ms-border-radius:8px; }
.ui-corner-tr { -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px; border-top-right-radius: 8px; -ms-border-radius:8px; }
.ui-corner-bl { -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 8px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px; border-bottom-left-radius: 8px; -ms-border-radius:8px; }
.ui-corner-br { -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px; border-bottom-right-radius: 8px; -ms-border-radius:8px; }
.ui-corner-top { -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px; border-top-left-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px; border-top-right-radius: 8px; -ms-border-radius:8px; }
.ui-corner-bottom { -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 8px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px; border-bottom-left-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px; border-bottom-right-radius: 8px; -ms-border-radius:8px; }
.ui-corner-right {  -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px; border-top-right-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px; border-bottom-right-radius: 8px; -ms-border-radius:8px; }
.ui-corner-left { -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px; border-top-left-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 8px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px; border-bottom-left-radius: 8px; -ms-border-radius:8px; }
.ui-corner-all { -moz-border-radius: 8px; -webkit-border-radius: 8px; border-radius: 8px; -ms-border-radius:8px; }
```

I believe this is cross browser tho old versions of Internet Explorer might not work with it

Comment: Cool that's very useful i will try it out! Thanks for the fast reply everyone xD

Comment: You shouldn't simply copy and paste random code where it seems to work. Please consider upvoting the answer of _Rob W_. He mentioned, that the `ms` prefix is required here.

Comment: yes i was about to comment on his answer to give creds to him :)

Comment: i am going to add your code that way if i decide to use partial round corners it will become very helpful

Comment: I don't know where in jquery you found the ms prefix, but http://blog.danielfriesen.name/2011/01/05/css3-border-radius-and-vendor-prefix-fud/ claims there never was "-ms-border-radius" and http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4972 seems to agree.

Comment: have you seen my comment on Rob's answer? probably not !

Comment: @DanyKhalife: the fact that you copied it from another answer doesn't make it correct, that was the main point of my comment. Sorry for my snarky preamble.

Answer (score 2):

These `-moz-`, `-o-`, `-webkit-` prefixes are necessary to  support older versions of the browsers. Contrary to popular belief, however, the `-ms-` prefix does not apply for the `border-radius` property. When IE started supporting `border-radius`, at version 9, the vendorless `border-radius` property was used<sup>[Link](http://blog.danielfriesen.name/2011/01/05/css3-border-radius-and-vendor-prefix-fud/)</sup>.

```
-moz-border-radius: 10px;    /* Gecko, Firefox */
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Safari, chrome */
-o-border-radius?: 10px;     /* Opera */
border-radius: 10px;         /* Modern browsers*/
```

Comment: The `-ms-` prefix only works in IE10+, doesn't it? Or IE9+ at the least?

Comment: Thanks for the `-ms-border-radius` part, i added it to mine but all credit for this goes to you :)

Comment: @JamWaffles Actually, according to [this source](http://blog.danielfriesen.name/2011/01/05/css3-border-radius-and-vendor-prefix-fud/), the `-ms-` for `border-radius` is not necessary, since IE supported the vendorless `border-radius` when it added support. IE9+

Comment: @RobW: so why mention -o- and -ms- properties, which according to the source you mention never existed? Not editing your answer, since you could have a reason to do this.

Comment: @Nickolay I added them to the comments, but forgot to update my original post. I have updated my answer, which should be fully correct now.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer 6-8 don't support css3, that's why `border-radius` doesn't work there.

For Internet Explorer 9 you can do rounded corners with (unprefixed) `border-radius` property
(http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/BorderRadius/)

For old webkit based browsers you need to use prefix -webkit.
For old mozilla based browsers you need to use prefix -moz.
For old version of Opera browser you need to use prefix -o.
For others you can use just a border-radius property without any prefixes

Your cross-browser code must be like that code below

```
{
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-o-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
}
```

For IE6-8 versions you need to use js plugins like http://css3pie.com/

Comment: Opera never supported `-o-border-radius`.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/). It can be a bit flakey in certain circumstances with opacity and the like however for the vast majority of sites it cuts down time taken to complete a cutup hugely.

Simply add `behaviour:url(/pie.htc);` to the *end* of your CSS3 declaration and IE will have full support for box-shadow, border-radius and linear gradients.